# Automating variable creation in the dataset based on lm specification

Tags: r, subset, formula

I have a dataset which looks as follows:

```
outcome <- c(1,2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1)
city <- rep(c("A", "B"),4)
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2000)
educ <- c("high", "low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "high", "low")
age <- c(25,35, 30, 29, 31, 40, 20, 23)
area <- c("city", "sub", "sub", "sub", "city", "city", "city", "city")
peopleinhouse <- c(2,4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2)
adataset <- data.frame(outcome, city, year, educ, age, area, peopleinhouse, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And I have a vector as follows:

```
avector <- c("outcome", "as.factor(city)", "year", "as.factor(educ):age", "log(age)", "as.factor(area):peopleinhouse")
```

I would like to automate the process of creating new (interaction) variables, with `avector` and `adataset` as input and `anotherdataset` as output.

I started as follows:

```
avector <- unlist(strsplit(avector , split=':', fixed=TRUE))

for (i in 1:length(avector)) {
  if (substr(avector[i], start = 1, stop = 9) == "as.factor") {
    adataset[,i] <- as.factor(adataset[,i])
  } else if(substr(avector[i], start = 1, stop = 3) == "log") {
      adataset[,i] <- log(adataset[,i])
  } else if (substr(avector [i], start = 1, stop = 1) == "I") {
      # Assumes a quadratic
      adataset[,i] <- adataset[,i]*adataset[,i]
  }
}
```

(This should work (works in my actual data) for single variables, but I get the error `Error in Math.factor(adataset[, i]) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors` in the example)

But I am not sure how to automate handling the interaction terms.

I need the interaction terms to be one variable because of `ivmodel` from library `ivmodel`.

The desired output would be a dataset which has the interaction terms as variables:

`as.factor(educ):age` and `as.factor(area):peopleinhouse` as one variable.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I am currently heading in the following direction:

```
# For every entry in the vector
for (i in 1:length(avector)) {
# if there is a ":" in the entry
    if (grepl(":", avector[i], fixed = FALSE)) {
# split the string into two string
        tmp <- unlist(strsplit(avector[i], split=':', fixed=FALSE))
# make a new variable
        adataset[,(length(avector)+i)] <- adataset[,tmp[1]]*adataset[,tmp[2]]
# Change the name of the new variable
        names(adataset[,(length(avector)+i)]) <- paste0(names(tmp[1]), names(tmp[2]))
    }
}
```

But I cannot get the syntax right..

EDIT II:

@Edo pointed out in the comments that `ivmodelFormula` takes formulas as well.
This removes part of my problem. However `?ivmodelFormula`  shows that for multiple instruments, these instruments are still provided by (a) vector(s):

```
# Multiple instruments
Z = card.data[,c("nearc4","nearc2")]
card.model2IV = ivmodelFormula(lwage ~ educ + exper + expersq + black + 
                                south + smsa + reg661 + 
                                reg662 + reg663 + reg664 + 
                                reg665 + reg666 + reg667 + 
                                reg668 + smsa66 | nearc4 + nearc2 +
                                exper + expersq + black + 
                                south + smsa + reg661 + 
                                reg662 + reg663 + reg664 + 
                                reg665 + reg666 + reg667 + 
                                reg668 + smsa66,data=card.data)
card.model2IV
```

Let's for example assume that I would like to run:

```
require(ivmodel)
Z <- adataset[, c("area", "educ", "peopleinhouse") ]
card.model2IV = ivmodelFormula(outcome ~ log(age) + as.factor(city) + year | area + educ + as.factor(city) + year)
card.model2IV
```

That works..

But what if I want to run `area:educ` as an interaction, like:

```
require(ivmodel)
Z <- adataset[, c("area", "educ", "peopleinhouse")]
another_card.model2IV = ivmodelFormula(outcome ~ log(age) + as.factor(city) + year | area:educ+ as.factor(city) + year)
another_card.model2IV
```

It runs, but it gives me the same output as `card.model2IV`, so I will still have to interact the instruments in the data.

Comment: I see that in the package you're using there is another function called `ivmodelFormula` that accept formulas as first parameter instead of vectors like  `ivmodel`. Why don't you use that?

Comment: I did not know that existed.. I wrote a serious bunch of code to work around that haha. I will try that immediately! Thanks!

Comment: @Edo I have checked it out. But it still does not allow for the instrument to be an interaction of factors, as `?ivmodelFormula` shows that the instruments are still provided with vectors.

Comment: share the formula you're using please.

Comment: @Edo I have made an second EDIT, `EDIT II` in the post. I hope that this explains the issue.

Comment: I don't understand why you say you get the same result. The printed output looks the same, however `all.equal(card.model2IV, another_card.model2IV)` is not `TRUE`. In particular, `card.model2IV$Z` and `another_card.model2IV$Z` are different and they look exactly as you would expect. It looks to me the function works as expected.

Comment: I believe the printed output looks the same just because the sample data is really short.

Comment: Thank you very much Edo. You have for a very large part solved the issue. Regretfully I have now figured out that `ivmodel` or `ivmodelFormula` does not supported multiple instrumentED variables. The idea was ultimately to replace `X1:X2` and  `X1:X3`, with `Z1:X2` and `Z1:X3`. But `ivmodelFormula`  then says `There must be exacty one endogenous variable! Please specify the formula correctly!`. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up our discussion in the comments, I'll give a final answer. Hopefully to be useful for other users that will look up for this.

The answer is divided in three parts: the first part is related to the solution of the first issue, the second part is related to the actual problem that @Tom faced, the third part is related to the usage of other packages to accomplish @Tom's actual goal.

---

**FIRST PART**

Initially, the problem was to create automatically a dataset with specific interactions and transformation given a an initial dataset and a vector of strings.

The good way to solve the problem is to use `model.matrix` as @krfurlong has suggested.

For example in this way.

Given the following data:

```
outcome <- c(1,2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1)
city <- rep(c("A", "B"),4)
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2000)
educ <- c("high", "low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "high", "low")
age <- c(25,35, 30, 29, 31, 40, 20, 23)
area <- c("city", "sub", "sub", "sub", "city", "city", "city", "city")
peopleinhouse <- c(2,4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2)
adataset <- data.frame(outcome, city, year, educ, age, area, peopleinhouse, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


avector <- c("outcome", "as.factor(city)", "year", "as.factor(educ):age", "log(age)", "as.factor(area):peopleinhouse")
```

You can achieve your goal in this way:

```
make_formula <- function(vec){
    
    x <- paste(vec[-1], collapse = " + ")
    frm <- paste(vec[1], x, sep = " ~ ")
    as.formula(frm)
    
}

as.data.frame(model.matrix(make_formula(avector), adataset))
```

```
  (Intercept) as.factor(city)B year log(age) as.factor(educ)high:age as.factor(educ)low:age as.factor(area)city:peopleinhouse as.factor(area)sub:peopleinhouse
1           1                0 2000 3.218876                      25                      0                                 2                                0
2           1                1 2001 3.555348                       0                     35                                 0                                4
3           1                0 2000 3.401197                       0                     30                                 0                                3
4           1                1 2000 3.367296                       0                     29                                 0                                3
5           1                0 2000 3.433987                      31                      0                                 5                                0
6           1                1 2001 3.688879                      40                      0                                 2                                0
7           1                0 2001 2.995732                      20                      0                                 1                                0
8           1                1 2000 3.135494                       0                     23                                 2                                0
```

---

**SECOND PART**

Eventually, we figured out that @Tom's actual goal was to run a specific model with `ivmodel` package.

The optimal way to solve this problem was to use the native function of `ivmodel` called `ivmodelFormula` that allows you set up a formula that handles transformations and interactions.

For example in this way.

```
library(ivmodel)

card.model2IV <- ivmodelFormula(outcome ~ log(age) + as.factor(city) + year | area + educ + as.factor(city) + year)

another_card.model2IV <- ivmodelFormula(outcome ~ log(age) + as.factor(city) + year | area:educ+ as.factor(city) + year)
```

Even though the printed output may look like the same in this specific case, it can be noted that `all.equal(card.model2IV, another_card.model2IV)` is not `TRUE` and, specifically, `card.model2IV$Z` and `another_card.model2IV$Z` look as expected.

```
card.model2IV$Z

#> 8 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>   areasub educlow
#> 1       .       .
#> 2       1       1
#> 3       1       1
#> 4       1       1
#> 5       .       .
#> 6       .       .
#> 7       .       .
#> 8       .       1


another_card.model2IV$Z

#> 8 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>   areacity.educhigh areasub.educhigh areacity.educlow areasub.educlow
#> 1                 1                .                .               .
#> 2                 .                .                .               1
#> 3                 .                .                .               1
#> 4                 .                .                .               1
#> 5                 1                .                .               .
#> 6                 1                .                .               .
#> 7                 1                .                .               .
#> 8                 .                .                1               .
```

---

**THIRD PART**

At the very end, we found out that the package doesn't handle multiple instrumented variables.

Seeing that that I'm no expert on the subject, if other users know more about it, they may feel free to update this answer so to make it more useful.

There are other packages that can deal with this kind of models.

Check out:

- [ivreg](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-9/topics/ivreg) from `AER` package
- [felm](https://rdrr.io/cran/lfe/man/felm.html) from `lfe` package

Comment: Thank you for this great answer Edo. 

ps. I will award you the bounty as soon as stackoverflow allows me (tomorrow).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but in this case it might be easier to "build"/"write" out the linear model's formula in an automated way instead of looping through your columns to perform the required data transformation steps.

- You can use the `collapse` argument in the `paste` function to re-write a vector of variables as an additive model
- Ensure you use a tilde (`~`) for identifying your dependent variable
- Use the helpful `as.formula` function to transform the string version of the formula into something R can evaluate

Here's your example, including the interaction terms as variables (note, I added more random data points to add some degrees of freedom in the model; if there are sufficient data points, the `lm` should also display the stdev's):

```
outcome <- c(1,2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1)
city <- rep(c("A", "B"),4)
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2000)
educ <- c("high", "low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "high", "low")
age <- c(25,35, 30, 29, 31, 40, 20, 23)
area <- c("city", "sub", "sub", "sub", "city", "city", "city", "city")
peopleinhouse <- c(2,4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2)
adataset <- data.frame(outcome, city, year, educ, age, area, peopleinhouse, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

avector <- c("outcome", "as.factor(city)", "year", "as.factor(educ):age", "log(age)", "as.factor(area):peopleinhouse")

tmp <- lm(data = adataset, formula = as.formula(paste0("outcome~", paste(avector[2:length(avector)], collapse = "+"))))
summary(tmp)
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste0("outcome~", paste(avector[2:length(avector)], 
    collapse = "+"))), data = adataset)

Residuals:
ALL 8 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients:
                                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                       1348.2888         NA      NA       NA
as.factor(city)B                    -0.9241         NA      NA       NA
year                                -0.6239         NA      NA       NA
log(age)                           -42.9461         NA      NA       NA
as.factor(educ)high:age              1.5155         NA      NA       NA
as.factor(educ)low:age               1.5318         NA      NA       NA
as.factor(area)city:peopleinhouse    0.3817         NA      NA       NA
as.factor(area)sub:peopleinhouse     0.5092         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 7 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid however that your answer does not offer a solution to my problem. I am familiar with the functionality you discuss. The issue is that I need the dataset to be updated, because I can only feed vectors to the package I want to use. I have no way of specifying an interaction term in the `ivmodel` function.

Comment: I copied your `adataset` to my post. I hope you don't mind. I agree that with have made for a better post with your dataset.

Comment: could you then perhaps use `model.matrix` to create the interaction terms - essentially one-hot-encoding the factor variables into dummy variables: 
`model.matrix(object = ~educ*age-1, data = adataset)`

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with `model.matrix`, can I attribute them to a vector? I think I am getting close to solution by the way (see my EDIT). If you would have any tips for that it would be great as well.